# How to Disprove Big O

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

I want to disprove $0.01n^3+ 0.0000001n^7$  is $O(n^3)$ and this is how I started.

The following is my proof:

Proof by Contradiction: assume the statement is true.

Then $0.01n^3+ 0.0000001n^7 < cn^3$ for some $c>0$ and for all $n>$1.

but after this point I got stuck. I honestly don't know what to do after this! Any help or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Minor remark: The word is disprove, meaning to prove false, instead of disapprove, meaning to express an unfavorable opinion.

Comment: The trick is to now divide by n^3

Comment: A minor nit: assuming the statement is true would mean that for some $c$ and $N_0$ it holds that $0.01n^3 + 0.0000001n^7 < c n^3$ for all $n > N_0$.